# What does こういうの refer to in こういうのって天然が一番怖いのよ

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> どこまでドジっ娘なのよ、あの子
>
> あはは…ま、まあ、わざとじゃないんだし
>
> こういうのって天然が一番怖いのよ

context: あの子 forgot something back in her room that they need and is in the process of going to get it and the other two then begin to talk.

I know that こういうの means "something like this"/things like this but honestly I can't see what "this" would be referring to. Does こういうのって in this case mean something like: as for things like this(in this case referring to forgetting important things)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> どこまでドジっ娘{こ}なのよ、あの子{こ}
>
> あはは…ま、まあ、わざとじゃないんだし
>
> こういうのって天然{てんねん}が一番怖{いちばんこわ}いのよ

「こういうの」 here refers to the "ドジ-ness" of people ***in general***.  「ドジ」 is a colloquial word meaning "clumsiness", "goof-ups", etc.

To let Wikipedia explain 「ドジっ娘」, see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojikko

The speaker is saying that among the different kinds of goofiness people display, the 「天然{てんねん}」= "natural, innate, etc." kind scares her the most.

> A: "How clumsy could she get?  That girl?"
>
> B: "Ahaha.. Well, you know, it isn't on purpose."
>
> A: "Speak of 'clumsy', it's the natural kind that scares me the most."

Comment: If I would like to say "I am clumsy" would it be correct to say 私、ドジなの? Or do I have to say ドジっ娘?