# What does ドジしたな mean?

Tags: translation, katakana

In a manga, there was this conversation,

> 「ギャハハー今度はまたすげードジしたな」

and I would like to know what the last part means, specifically ドジしたな.

Summarising, this is what I would like to have answered:

1. I think ドジ means something like clumsy. Then, is ドジした something like "did in a clumsy manner"?
2. Why is ドジ written in かたかな?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25762/what-does-%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae-refer-to-in-%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e5%a4%a9%e7%84%b6%e3%81%8c%e4%b8%80%e7%95%aa%e6%80%96%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%82%88/25766#25766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ドジ(を)する is basically closer to "to make a mistake" rather than "to do something in a clumsy way". It tends to refer to funny and/or affordable mistakes typically made by a [dojikko character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojikko). There is another godan verb [ドジる](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%89%E3%82%B8%E3%82%8B), which may be a little more common (ドジった, ドジってばっかり, ...) and has almost the same meaning. (You cannot directly modify ドジる with すごい, though)
2. I think [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15102/5010) answers your question, although there is not even a known kanji version in this case. Few people know or care about the etymology of ドジ.

Comment: Is the を particle optional? Like in 勉強(を)する?

Comment: Yes, just like 勉強する.